# Understanding git branch all

Tags: git, git-branch

What does the the arrow (->) mean here:

```
* development
  master
  production
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/production
  remotes/origin/development
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/production
```

I'm just trying to get a real handle on git, so I'm diggin' deep and finding out that the further I go, the less I know about git, haha.

Comment: Think I got it. Is that pointing to the latest commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`remotes/origin/HEAD` `->` `origin/production`

means

`remotes/origin/HEAD` is pointing to `origin/production`

---

`origin/HEAD` is not a self-contained branch. It is just a pointer to the "main" branch, the one you get after a clone.

Try `git symbolic-ref refs/heads/foo refs/heads/master`. Afterwards `git branch` will show:

```
foo -> master
```

Then `foo` is just another name for `master`.

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't the Head the branch that's currently checked out?

Comment: Well, `HEAD` is a pointer (aka symbolic-ref) to the current branch. You can see it with `cat .git/HEAD` or `git symbolic-ref HEAD`. In your case `origin/HEAD` is the same concept on the remote repository, it is used by `git clone` to determine what branch to check out directly after the clone.

Comment: Hmmm... cool. Strange, I cd'd over to my remote repo and changed the HEAD with git checkout development (that moves the HEAD right?), but then when I cd'd back to my local repo (I'm simulated remotes by just having another file on my computer) and logged again, the HEAD hadn't changed.

Comment: @Costa `HEAD` has different meanings in git in different contexts, and in this case you've gotten two different contexts confused. `HEAD` on a non-bare remote repo is just the currently checked out revision on the remote, but it's unrelated to the `HEAD` reference that a clone of that remote repo would have. The only way to change the reference on the local repo (that I know of) is to use what @michas mentioned, `git symbolic-ref`. You can read more about it in the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-symbolic-ref.html).

Comment: @Costa for what it's worth, the fact that these somewhat related but different references are named the same thing ***is confusing*** at first (it's not intuitive), until you understand what each one actually represents in their own contexts.

Comment: Hmmm... okay, I definitely need to go through more of git pro, documentation and actually just trying stuff out. Thanks so much!!! I'm gonna keep trying : )