# Why does my remote repository show branch named HEAD on github.com?

Tags: git, github

Here is the branch dropdown on Github.com for my repository.

```
$ git branch -r
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
origin/dev
origin/master
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363543/understanding-git-branch-all/22363716#22363716

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is git HEAD, exactly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304087/what-is-git-head-exactly)

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question. This one is about `origin/HEAD` which is different from `HEAD`.

Comment: Yes but it's not a branch, so should not show up like that in the dropdown on Github.com. My other remote repositories don't.

Answer (score 1):

`HEAD` is not a branch, but it is a reference. References in git are basically pointers to commits with a name attached. In fact, branches and tags are references but there are also other types.

Now, `HEAD` is a special reference that points to the currently checked out commit. In the case of a remote repository, it's the default commit that gets checked out if you clone the repo. This points to a branch most of the time. The common default is the `master` branch which is the case here too.

Comment: See also [What is git HEAD, exactly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304087/what-is-git-head-exactly)

Answer (score 1):

`HEAD` is not really a branch but a pointer (aka symref) to a branch (or commit).

Your local `HEAD` points to the currently checked out branch. The remote `origin/HEAD` points to the main branch, i.e. the branch checked out after a clone.

Comment: Yes but it's not a branch, so should not show up like that in the dropdown on Github.com. My other remote repositories don't.